# Redirect page without losing SEO

Tags: asp.net, redirect, seo, dns

I want to change address of my online page but want to make sure that I won't lose any SEO thing.

e.g. want to move a page from http://example.com/1.aspx to http://example2.com/a.aspx

Is it possible to do this?

If yes, then how?

If no, what best could be done here if I have to move page and there is no way to stop this.

Comment: I would not dare answer after seeing how someone's voting. 301 is the way to go though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a 301 permanent redirect.

Comment: 301 is best you will loose some link juice but you need to make sure you redirect from page to page not just one giant global one... see this http://j.mp/9NeDN3 its google's official explanation

Answer (score 1):

Using an HTTP redirect code (probably 301 Moved Permanently) is the best way to do this, as search engines clearly understand what it means.

The exact nature depends on which web server you are using, but google should help you find that answer.

Comment: Wow, someone's in a bad mood today

Answer (score 0):

Erm, what?

You could do a re-direct from 1.aspx to 2.aspx until 2.aspx has reasonable SEO.

kinda unsure what it is you're asking here

**edit**

ah ok i see after your edit.

Yeah not really do-able i don't think as crawlers rate pages and if you change your page then the seo for it will go.

however, the rating for your site will still be there so you shouldn't lose too much.

Comment: downvoter!  i trust there is a reason for it and if there is that you have a solution